# I am getting pip version upgrade message while installing pygmaps

Tags: python, pip, version

I am getting this error while installing `pygmaps` package in pycharm.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygmaps (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygmaps
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have already upgraded pip version to 19.1.1, but still showing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install git+https://github.com/thearn/pygmaps-extended`  can you try this one ?

if it doesnt work

https://code.google.com/archive/p/pygmaps/downloads   go to this link and download it manually and add to your site-packages

Comment: did u try the manually ? in this link there 2 file .py and tar.gz try both of them it should work

Comment: copied both the files into site-packages folder

Comment: try put the pygmaps.py file on your project same directory with main.py or whatever the name is

Comment: then make the question solved for the other members u are welcome

Comment: İsa GİRİŞKEN , I am getting error in my python code regarding flask can you please help me with code? I can share file with you.

Comment: firstly like ı said mark as answered the question for the other member then send your files to giriskenisa@gmail.com :)